# why is this question yellow?

Tags: discussion

[What is the Effect of Multiplying a Function by the Unit Impulse Function in the Frequency Domain?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/68076/what-is-the-effect-of-multiplying-a-function-by-the-unit-impulse-function-in-the)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you mean this?

[image]

That is because you're [watching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312180/295232) one of the question's tag. This might have happened inadvertently (it's rather easy to click the Watch Tag button in the tag popup and not immediately notice it).

Comment: thanks.  i had no idea and i assumed that everyone saw the yellow like i did.